# Service Worker Scope

Tags: scope, service-worker

[image]

Isn't this a wrong diagram, or am I missing something? Both **trending.html** & **fav** directory already under the worker's scope, so why it's skipping **trending.html** request?!

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers#Why_is_my_service_worker_failing_to_register